# IBM MQ - FFDC - CSIException: JMSCS0002 when I try to run from console

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar, ibm-mq

I writed some JAR which has a wrap communication with IBM MQ.
When I try use that JAR in other app it works only when I run it in IDE or in console as maven:

> "C:\Program Files\Apache\maven\bin\mvn.bat" -Dexec.args="-classpath %classpath xx.xxx.xxx.Application" -Dexec.executable="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar;C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\maven-nblib\netbeans-cos.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec

When I try to run it in that way:

> java -jar MyJar.jar

I got error:

```
FFDC called in uninitialized Trace module



                                    FDCTitle


Product          :- ProductName
Date/Time        :- Mon Apr 25 21:27:53 CEST 2016
System time      :- 1461612473559
Operating System :- Windows 7
UserID           :- myUser
Java Vendor      :- Oracle Corporation
Java Version     :- 24.71-b01

Source Class     :- com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiDefaultThreadPool
Source Method    :- enqueue(Runnable)
ProbeID          :- XN009001
Thread           :- name=main priority=5 group=main ccl=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4bcd2d49

                                      Data
                                      ----

|   CompCode   :-  2
|   Reason     :-  2195
|   exception  :-  ExceptionDepth is 2
|   exception  :-
|   |   Cause:1       :-  com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CSIException: JMSCS0002
|   |   Message:1     :-  JMSCS0002
|   |   StackTrace:1  :-  com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CSIException: JMSCS0002
|   |           at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.PIWorkQueueManager.enqueueItem(PIWorkQueueManager.java:54)
|   |           at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.enqueue(WorkQueueManager.java:232)
|   |           at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.enqueue(WorkQueueManager.java:200)
|   |           at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiDefaultThreadPool.enqueue(JmqiDefaultThreadPool.java:78)
|   |           at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.setUpAsyncMode(RemoteConnection.java:1900)
|   |           at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.initSess(RemoteConnection.java:1664)
|   |           at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:838)
|   |           at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:409)
|   |           at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:305)
|   |           at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
|   |           at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1868)
|   |           at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1396)
|   |           at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:342)
|   |           at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6865)
|   |           at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6221)
|   |           at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
|   |           at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:233)
|   |           at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6016)
|   |           at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111)
|   |           at xx.xxx.xxx.cepapi.CEPSessionImpl.creteConnection(CEPSessionImpl.java:84)
|   |           at xx.xxx.xxx.cepapi.CEPSessionImpl.connect(CEPSessionImpl.java:44)
|   |           at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.cep.CEPManager.connect(CEPManager.java:45)
|   |           at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.ApplicationManager.initialiceCEP(ApplicationManager.java:33)
|   |           at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.ApplicationManager.initializeApplication(ApplicationManager.java:23)
|   |           at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.console.ConsoleAdapter.startAction(ConsoleAdapter.java:93)
|   |           at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.console.ConsoleAdapter.runConsole(ConsoleAdapter.java:42)
|   |           at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.Application.main(Application.java:22)
|   |
|   job        :-  com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread@b7918cf

                              Version information
                              -------------------

Java Message Service Client
8.0.0.0
p000-L140506
Production
Component Name:  com.ibm.msg.client.jms
CMVC:            p000-L140506
Class Name:      class com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JMSComponent
Factory Class:   null
Version:         8.0.0.0
Component Title: Java Message Service Client
Jar location:    file:/D:/Project/XXXXX/target/xxxxx-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

WebSphere MQ classes for Java Message Service
8.0.0.0
p000-L140506
Production
Component Name:  com.ibm.mq.jms
CMVC:            p000-L140506
Class Name:      class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQJMSComponent
Factory Class:   null
Version:         8.0.0.0
Component Title: WebSphere MQ classes for Java Message Service
Jar location:    file:/D:/Project/XXXXX/target/xxxxx-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Provider
8.0.0.0
p000-L140506
Production
Component Name:  com.ibm.msg.client.wmq
CMVC:            p000-L140506
Class Name:      class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent
Factory Class:   class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory
Version:         8.0.0.0
Component Title: IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Provider
Jar location:    file:/D:/Project/XXXXX/target/xxxxx-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar



                                  Stack trace
                                  -----------

Stack trace to show the location of the FFST call
|   FFST Location  :-  java.lang.Exception
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.getCurrentPosition(Trace.java:2049)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.createFFSTString(Trace.java:1960)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffstInternal(Trace.java:1847)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffst(Trace.java:1657)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiDefaultThreadPool.enqueue(JmqiDefaultThreadPool.java:92)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.setUpAsyncMode(RemoteConnection.java:1900)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.initSess(RemoteConnection.java:1664)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:838)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:409)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:305)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1868)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1396)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:342)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6865)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6221)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:233)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6016)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111)
|       at xx.xxx.xxx.cepapi.CEPSessionImpl.creteConnection(CEPSessionImpl.java:84)
|       at xx.xxx.xxx.cepapi.CEPSessionImpl.connect(CEPSessionImpl.java:44)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.cep.CEPManager.connect(CEPManager.java:45)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.ApplicationManager.initialiceCEP(ApplicationManager.java:33)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.ApplicationManager.initializeApplication(ApplicationManager.java:23)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.console.ConsoleAdapter.startAction(ConsoleAdapter.java:93)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.console.ConsoleAdapter.runConsole(ConsoleAdapter.java:42)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.Application.main(Application.java:22)
|

                            Property Store Contents
                            -----------------------

All currently set properties
|   MQJMS_TRACE_DIR                                               :-
|   MQJMS_TRACE_LEVEL                                             :-
|   awt.toolkit                                                   :-  sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.Channels.DefRecon                              :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.MQCCSID                                        :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.MQCLNTCF                                       :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.MQIPADDRV                                      :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.MQSSLPOLLTIMEOUT                               :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.MQ_LCLADDR                                     :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.ClntRcvBuffSize                            :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.ClntSndBuffSize                            :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.Connect_Timeout                            :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.EndPort                                    :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.StrPort                                    :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.AmqRandomNumberType                       :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.PasswordProtection                        :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.libpath                                   :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication                    :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.connector.JCARuntimeHelper                         :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.ignoreCCDTCertificateLabel                    :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.jms.replyToStyle                                   :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.jms.tuning.usePersistenceFromMD                    :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.mq.localAddress                                       :-
|   com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.ffst.suppress               :-  0
|   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.forceAllowClientConnection             :-  false
|   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.forceDontUseJmqiWorkerThread  :-  false
|   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.forceDontUseSharedHconn       :-  false
|   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.forceUseJmqiWorkerThread      :-  false
|   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.overrideInheritRRSContext              :-  false
|   com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.overrideProviderVersion                :-  <null>
|   com.ibm.vm.bitmode                                            :-  <null>
|   file.encoding                                                 :-  Cp1250
|   file.encoding.pkg                                             :-  sun.io
|   file.separator                                                :-  \
|   java.awt.graphicsenv                                          :-  sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
|   java.awt.printerjob                                           :-  sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
|   java.class.path                                               :-  target\xxxxx-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
|   java.class.version                                            :-  51.0
|   java.endorsed.dirs                                            :-  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\endorsed
|   java.ext.dirs                                                 :-  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
|   java.home                                                     :-  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
|   java.io.tmpdir                                                :-  c:\temp\
|   java.library.path                                             :-  C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ_1
\java\lib;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ_1\java\lib64;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\W
INDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;D:\Program Files\Apache\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\IB
M\WebSphere MQ\bin64;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\samples\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ_1\bin64;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebS
phere MQ_1\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ_1\tools\c\samples\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyFrom Trial\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bi
n;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm;.
|   java.runtime.name                                             :-  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
|   java.runtime.version                                          :-  1.7.0_71-b14
|   java.specification.name                                       :-  Java Platform API Specification
|   java.specification.vendor                                     :-  Oracle Corporation
|   java.specification.version                                    :-  1.7
|   java.vendor                                                   :-  Oracle Corporation
|   java.vendor.url                                               :-  http://java.oracle.com/
|   java.vendor.url.bug                                           :-  http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
|   java.version                                                  :-  1.7.0_71
|   java.vm.info                                                  :-  mixed mode
|   java.vm.name                                                  :-  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
|   java.vm.specification.name                                    :-  Java Virtual Machine Specification
|   java.vm.specification.vendor                                  :-  Oracle Corporation
|   java.vm.specification.version                                 :-  1.7
|   java.vm.vendor                                                :-  Oracle Corporation
|   java.vm.version                                               :-  24.71-b01
|   line.separator                                                :-

|   os.arch                                                       :-  amd64
|   os.name                                                       :-  <null>
|   os.version                                                    :-  6.1
|   path.separator                                                :-  ;
|   sun.arch.data.model                                           :-  <null>
|   sun.boot.class.path                                           :-  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\
lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jfr.jar
;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\classes
|   sun.boot.library.path                                         :-  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
|   sun.cpu.endian                                                :-  little
|   sun.cpu.isalist                                               :-  amd64
|   sun.desktop                                                   :-  windows
|   sun.io.unicode.encoding                                       :-  UnicodeLittle
|   sun.java.command                                              :-  target\xxxxx-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
|   sun.java.launcher                                             :-  SUN_STANDARD
|   sun.jnu.encoding                                              :-  Cp1250
|   sun.management.compiler                                       :-  HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
|   sun.os.patch.level                                            :-  Service Pack 1
|   user.country                                                  :-  US
|   user.country.format                                           :-  PL
|   user.dir                                                      :-  D:\Project\XXXXX
|   user.home                                                     :-  C:\Users\myUser
|   user.language                                                 :-  en
|   user.language.format                                          :-  pl
|   user.name                                                     :-  myUser
|   user.script                                                   :-
|   user.timezone                                                 :-  Europe/Belgrade
|   user.variant                                                  :-

                           WorkQueueMananger Contents
                           --------------------------

|   Maintain ThreadPool size     :-  false
|   Maximum ThreadPool size      :-  -1
|   ThreadPool inactive timeout  :-  0
|   unavailable -                :-  com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CSIException: JMSCS0002

                               Runtime properties
                               ------------------

|   Available processors         :-  8
|   Free memory in bytes (now)   :-  87386128
|   Max memory in bytes          :-  1888485376
|   Total memory in bytes (now)  :-  127401984

                           Component Manager Contents
                           --------------------------

Common Services Components:
Messaging Provider Components:
|   CMVC             :-  p000-L140506
|   Class Name       :-  class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent
|   Component Name   :-  com.ibm.msg.client.wmq
|   Component Title  :-  IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Provider
|   Factory Class    :-  class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory
|   Jar location     :-  file:/D:/Project/XXXXX/target/xxxxx-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
|   Version          :-  8.0.0.0




                         Provider Specific Information
                         -----------------------------

Overview of JMS System
Num. Connections : 0
Num. Sessions    : 0
Num. Consumers   : 0
Num. Producers   : 0

Detailed JMS System Information
Connections      :
Sessions         :
Consumers        :
Producers        :


FFDC called in uninitialized Trace module



                                    FDCTitle


Product          :- ProductName
Date/Time        :- Mon Apr 25 21:27:53 CEST 2016
System time      :- 1461612473705
Operating System :- Windows 7
UserID           :- myUser
Java Vendor      :- Oracle Corporation
Java Version     :- 24.71-b01

Source Class     :- com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.PINLSServices
Source Method    :- getMessage(String,HashMap)
ProbeID          :- XC003002
Thread           :- name=main priority=5 group=main ccl=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4bcd2d49

                                      Data
                                      ----

Data        :- none

                              Version information
                              -------------------

Java Message Service Client
8.0.0.0
p000-L140506
Production
Component Name:  com.ibm.msg.client.jms
CMVC:            p000-L140506
Class Name:      class com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JMSComponent
Factory Class:   null
Version:         8.0.0.0
Component Title: Java Message Service Client
Jar location:    file:/D:/Project/XXXXX/target/xxxxx-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

WebSphere MQ classes for Java Message Service
8.0.0.0
p000-L140506
Production
Component Name:  com.ibm.mq.jms
CMVC:            p000-L140506
Class Name:      class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQJMSComponent
Factory Class:   null
Version:         8.0.0.0
Component Title: WebSphere MQ classes for Java Message Service
Jar location:    file:/D:/Project/XXXXX/target/xxxxx-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Provider
8.0.0.0
p000-L140506
Production
Component Name:  com.ibm.msg.client.wmq
CMVC:            p000-L140506
Class Name:      class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent
Factory Class:   class com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory
Version:         8.0.0.0
Component Title: IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Provider
Jar location:    file:/D:/Project/XXXXX/target/xxxxx-2.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar



                                  Stack trace
                                  -----------

Stack trace to show the location of the FFST call
|   FFST Location  :-  java.lang.Exception
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.getCurrentPosition(Trace.java:2049)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.createFFSTString(Trace.java:1960)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffstInternal(Trace.java:1847)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffst(Trace.java:1657)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.PINLSServices.getMessage(PINLSServices.java:132)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.getMessage(NLSServices.java:238)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:210)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:406)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6865)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6221)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:233)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6016)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111)
|       at xx.xxx.xxx.cepapi.CEPSessionImpl.creteConnection(CEPSessionImpl.java:84)
|       at xx.xxx.xxx.cepapi.CEPSessionImpl.connect(CEPSessionImpl.java:44)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.cep.CEPManager.connect(CEPManager.java:45)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.ApplicationManager.initialiceCEP(ApplicationManager.java:33)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.ApplicationManager.initializeApplication(ApplicationManager.java:23)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.console.ConsoleAdapter.startAction(ConsoleAdapter.java:93)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.console.ConsoleAdapter.runConsole(ConsoleAdapter.java:42)
|       at xx.xxx.xxxxxx.Application.main(Application.java:22)
|
```

...

Any idea what that can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is load IBM classes from outside of JAR.